# Each of us is responsible for their conduct

Tags: grammar, grammaticality

Each of us is responsible for their conduct. or: Each of us are responsible for their conduct.
Is this correct? Or I have to use the verb in plural?

Comment: I would say "is", but either way the sentence seems odd because of "their": each of us is responsible for [someone else's] conduct?

Answer (score 4):

Each refers separately to the items in a group. Check dictionaries to see examples. Each is therefore singular.

Examples: each of us is responsible for our conduct; each member of the audience is sitting; each body is dead.

Comment: Do you mean *Each of us is responsible for their (= **someone else's**) conduct*; or *Each of us is responsible for **our own** conduct.*?

Comment: I ignored this ambiguity because it is a separate issue.